# GlOrtho not working properly

Tags: c++, opengl

I am using GLUT and for some reason my glOrtho isn't working properly.

This is my code:

```
#include"Dependencies\glew\glew.h"
#include"Dependencies\freeglut\freeglut.h"
#include<iostream>
void render(void)
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 1280, 720, 0, 0, 1);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    float x = 0.0;
    float y = 0;
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
        glVertex2f(x, y);
        glVertex2f(x + .1, y);
        glVertex2f(x + .1, y + .1);
        glVertex2f(x, y + .1);
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
void closeCallback()
{

    std::cout << "GLUT:\t Finished" << std::endl;
    glutLeaveMainLoop();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(32, 32);
    glutInitWindowSize(1280, 720);
    glutCreateWindow("MahGame");
    glutSetOption(GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE, GLUT_ACTION_GLUTMAINLOOP_RETURNS);

    glewInit();

    glutDisplayFunc(render);
    glutCloseFunc(closeCallback);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Even though I set my x and y floats to 0 I renders it in the middle, and when I try something like x + 50, it is SUPER huge, I have to make it x + 0.5f so that my triangle is small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting your projection matrix correctly:

```
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, 1280, 720, 0, 0, 1);
glLoadIdentity();
```

The second `glLoadIdentity()` completely overwrites whatever matrix was set before, so that your `glOrtho()` does not have any effect at all (besides consuming some CPU cycles).